# dom4j attributeValue with qualified name

Tags: java, android, xml, dom4j

I'm using dom4j to parse AndroidManifestFile.xml. However I found that it treats "android:xxx" attribute strangely.

For example:

```
    <receiver android:name="ProcessOutgoingCallTest" android:exported="false"                                                                                                              
        android:enabled="false">                                                                                                                                                           
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">                                                                                                                                               
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />                                                                                                              
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                                                                                                                    
        </intent-filter>                                                                                                                                                                   
    </receiver>
```

The return value `e.attributeValue("android:exported")` will be `null` however using `e.attributeValue("exported")` will obtain the correct string (but I don't like this way since it may match more than expected). Meanwhile, `e.attributeValue(new QName("android:exported"))` will still be a null string.

What's the correct way to get the attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `android:` is nothing more than a `namespace` in XML.

If there is only one possible namespace, it is ok to write `e.attributeValue("exported")`.

> QName represents a qualified name value of an XML element or attribute. It consists of a local name and a Namespace instance

```
QName(String name)       
QName(String name, Namespace namespace)    
QName(String name, Namespace namespace, String qualifiedName)
```

thus, `new QName("android:exported")` is wrong, and the correct form is

```
new QName("exported", new Namespace("android", "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"))
```

If you miss its namespace here, you take it as `NO_NAMESPACE` for default.

```
public QName(String name) {
    this(name, Namespace.NO_NAMESPACE);
}
```

Example:

```
        Element root = document.getRootElement();
        Namespace namespace = new Namespace("android", "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android");
        for(Iterator i = root.elementIterator("receiver"); i.hasNext();)
        {
            Element e = (Element)i.next();
            System.out.println(e.attributeValue("exported"));
            System.out.println(e.attributeValue(new QName("exported", namespace)));
        }
```

Comment: is it because "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" defined in a typical AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes. You only have to consider how to use `QName` and namespace related things.